# Can we say $\| f\|_{\dot H^s(\mathbb R^n)} \le \| f \|_{\dot H^q(\mathbb R^n)}$ if $s\le q$?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

If $s\le q$, then can we say that
$$
\| f\|_{\dot H^s(\mathbb R^n)} \le \| f \|_{\dot H^q(\mathbb R^n)}
$$
holds? Here the homogeneous Sobolev seminorm $\|f\|_{\dot H^s(\mathbb R^n)} = \|(-\Delta)^{s/2}f\|_{L^2(\mathbb R^n)}$, where $\Delta$ is the Laplacian in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: could you add a small remark to your notation? does the dot ${\dot H^s(\mathbb R^n)}$ mean you are looking at the closure of the smooth test functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in general this is false.  Consider as an elementary example $s=0$, $q=2$ (so that we don't have to deal with fractional derivatives or anything like this).  We are inspired by the following observation: if $f(x)=C$ is a nonzero constant function, then $\|f\|_{\dot{H}^2} = \|-\Delta f\|_{L^2} = 0$, while naively "$\|f\|_{L^2} = +\infty$". There are scare quotes here for a reason; typically (as @user190080 mentioned) we define $\dot{H}^s$ as the closure in the $\dot{H}^s$ norm of smooth test functions (which have compact support).

So instead we argue by scaling.  Let $\phi$ be *any* smooth test function on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and define $\phi_r(x) = \phi(rx)$.  Then
$$
\|\phi_r\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)} = r^{-n/2} \|\phi\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)},
$$
while
$$
\|\phi_r\|_{\dot{H}^2(\mathbb{R}^n)} = r^{2-n/2}\|\phi\|_{\dot{H}^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}.
$$
Sending $r\to 0$, we see that this contradicts the inequality you want.

Two more comments.  An intuitive way to test out these relationships is to  use localized wavepackets as examples.  See Terry Tao's answer at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17736/way-to-memorize-relations-between-the-sobolev-spaces for an explanation of how to do this.

Second, there are spaces where the inequality you want is true.  In particular this works on hyperbolic space, or any space with infinite 
volume and a spectral gap.  The reason I mention this is to point out that the scaling argument really is needed to make the example rigorous, and the simplistic example of a constant function can lead you astray.

Comment: do you actually mean $\|\phi_r\|_{\dot{H}^2(\mathbb{R}^n)} = r^{2-n/2}\|\phi\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}$? Since you have to differentiate twice in according to the Laplacian...

Comment: No, the idea is that $\|\phi\|_{\dot{H}^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}$ and $\|\phi\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}$ are comparable originally, so that $\|\phi\|_{\dot{H}^2(\mathbb{R}^n)} \leq C \|\phi\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}$ for some constant $C$.  This then gets amplified so that $\|\phi_r\|_{\dot{H}^2(\mathbb{R}^n)} \leq Cr^2 \|\phi_r\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}$, and this makes the contradiction as $r\to 0$.

Comment: Sorry, in my first response I focused more on the spaces for the norms (since you had the $H^2$ Sobolev norm on the left and $L^2$ on the right).  But now I see your question about the exponents; and you are correct.  I will fix it now.

Comment: ok...I just thought since $\|\phi_r\|_{\dot H^2(\mathbb R^n)} := \|(-\Delta)\phi_r\|_{L^2(\mathbb R^n)}=r^2 \|\phi_r\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}=r^{2-n/2}\|\phi\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}$ which would then immediately generate a contradiction for the inequality using $\|\phi_r\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)} = r^{-n/2} \|\phi\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}$, so actually everything would cancel out and you just have the $r$-terms left

Comment: The problem is in your second equality; we do not have that $(-\Delta)\phi_r = r^2\phi_r$, but instead that $(-\Delta)\phi_r(x) = r^2 (-\Delta\phi)(rx)$.

Comment: ahh of course, good old chain rule, thanks a lot! So the bottom line is that the inequality can't hold in the limit with $r$ to $0$ which is especially easy to see for $n=1$